# In mongoDB how to determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

"ElemMatch" tests that at least one item in array match the query.
I just want to test all items (like Enumerable.All in LINQ)

```
Query.ElemMatch("Prices", Query.GTE("Value", criteria.MinPrice))
```

any suggestion will be accepted. (mongo script, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of testing that every element matches the condition, you can use `Query.Not` to ensure that none of them fail the opposite condition.

e.g. Where all Values are not less than `criteria.MinPrice`

```
Query.Not(Query.ElemMatch("Prices", Query.LT("Value", criteria.MinPrice)));
```

This approach will only work if you have a consistent schema where every element in `Prices` always has a `Value`, as `Prices` that don't have a `Value` won't fail the check.

If `Prices` may be empty you may want to exclude those docs

```
Query.And(
    Query.Exists("Prices.0"),
    Query.Not(Query.ElemMatch("Prices", Query.LT("Value", criteria.MinPrice)))
);
```